# How to show $\frac{2-x}{2+x} \le e^{-x}$ for $x\ge0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inequality, exponential-function, geometric-progressions

Let $x\geq0$. Show that:
 $$\frac{2-x}{2+x} \le e^{-x}.$$

I have some troubles to prove it. Would you give me any hint?

Comment: is $e^{-x}$ ever negative? For which $x$ is this inequality "interesting"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Construct the function $f(x)=(2-x)-e^{-x}(2+x)$. We need to show that $f(x)\le 0,\ \forall x\ge 0$.

Now, note that $f'(x)=-1+e^{-x}(2+x)-e^{-x}=-1+e^{-x}(1+x)\le 0$ for $x\ge 0$. The last inequality follows since $e^{x}=\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n/n!\ge 1+x\ \forall\  x\ge 0$.

Thus, $f$ is a monotonically decreasing function for $x\ge 0$. Hence, $f(x)\le f(0)\ \forall x\ge 0$. Since $f(0)=0$, the result follows.$\quad\blacksquare$

Comment: Thanks for you answer.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg, it was meant to be a hint, though I almost gave a solution, and since $e^x\ge 1+x,\ \forall x\ge 0$, it is actually trivial to translate it to a proof.

Comment: Ok, let me then edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

We need to prove that 
$$(2-x)e^x\leq2+x$$ or
$$x(e^x+1)\geq2(e^x-1)$$ or
$f(x)\geq0$, where
$$f(x)=x-\frac{2(e^x-1)}{e^x+1}$$ and calculate $f'(x)$:
$$f'(x)=1-\frac{4e^x}{(e^x+1)^2}=\frac{(e^x-1)^2}{(e^x+1)^2}\geq0,$$
which gives $f(x)\geq f(0)=0$ and we are done!

Answer (score 3):

We can assume that $0 \le x < 2$. Then, using the geometric series,
$$
 \frac{2+x}{2-x} = 1 + \frac{x}{1 - \frac 12 x} =  1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{2^{n-1}}
 \ge 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} = e^x \, .
$$

*Remark:* $(2-x)/(2+x)$ is the [Padé approximant of order [1/1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant) for $f(x) = \exp(-x)$, 
that is the (unique) rational function of the form
$$ 
R(x) =  \frac{a_0 + a_1 x}{1 + b_1 x}
$$
such that $R(0) = f(0), R'(0) = f'(0)$ and $R''(0) = f''(0)$.

Comment: I would like to see the first equality expanded to show the steps. I know it's equivalent to $1/2^n+1/2^n=1/2^{n-1}$.

Comment: @martycohen: I just inserted an intermediate step. Is that sufficient?

Comment: Yep. I find it interesting that your expansion is different than the one I had in mind. They both work.

Comment: Would you know why $(-1)^n (e^x - [m/n])$ has positive Taylor series?

Comment: @orangeskid: Is that a question regarding my proof, or a add-on question?

Comment: It's an add-on, noticed by testing with Mathematica.   Just starting with Pade approximations.  I've seen some complicated formulas (classical) for the $[m/n]$ on m-overflow.

Comment: @orangeskid: I don't know much about Padé approximants, so I cannot answer your question right now. My answer does not make use of it, it was just an observation how the terms in that inequality are related.